# How to recreate a .pub file

Tags: java

I'm trying to replace a test cert in an old code base. However, I keep getting the below exception at the line `X509EncodedKeySpec spec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(x509EncodedPublicKey)`;. I tried inspecting the old cert which is a `.pub` file and that is in unreadable format. I tried to generate self-signed certs myself and not matter what type of public I create, I still keep getting the same exception. How can I inspect the existing certificate and recreate another cert like that.

Exception

```
java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: invalid key format
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.engineGeneratePublic(RSAKeyFactory.java:205)
    at java.security.KeyFactory.generatePublic(KeyFactory.java:334)

Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: invalid key format
    at sun.security.x509.X509Key.decode(X509Key.java:387)
    at sun.security.x509.X509Key.decode(X509Key.java:402)
```

when I tried to read the cert I got the below exception
$ openssl x509 -in test.pub -text -noout
unable to load certificate
4420640428:error:09FFF06C:PEM routines:CRYPTO_internal:no start line:/m/pem_lib.c:684:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that there is an option in the `keystore explorer` tool where the `.pub` file can be extracted in 2 formats. One is as `.pem` the other is `without pem`. When we disable the `.pem` option, the file is extracted with `.pub` and encoded as mentioned in the question.